# Is this why bidirectional propositions affirm the same exact things?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I am trying to justify why if two propositions P and Q mutually entail each other, a universe where we know P is true and a universe where we know Q is true do not differ in anyway to our knowledge. I have reasoned as follows:

There is a set, call it A, which is qualities the universe must have if P is true, and a set, call it B, which is qualities the universe must have if Q is true. The set of qualities the universe must have if P is true also includes the set of qualities the universe has if Q is true, as P implies Q; therefore B ⊆ A. For the same reason, for the universe in which Q is true, A ⊆ B. Therefore A=B, and the universes have the same qualities.

I am wondering if this reasoning is correct, and if there is a simpler way to justify that for bidirectional propositions P and Q, a universe where we only know P is true and a universe where we only know Q is true are the same.

Thanks

Comment: If you consider only *propositional logic*, you have to consider [truth valuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(logic)): "an assignment of truth values to propositional variables". In this case when P implies Q we have that the set of valuations satisfying $Q$ (call it $V_Q$) is a subset of the set satisfying $P$ (call it $V_P$) i.e. $V_Q \subseteq V_P$. And the same for Q implies P. Conclusion: P equiv Q iff $V_P = V_Q$.

Comment: So yes, from the point of view of truth-functional logic, were the only "meaning" of a proposition is its truth value, two propositions that are equivalent affirm the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is informal but the idea makes sense. Your phrasing seems a bit loose with the distinction between "qualities the universe *has*" and "qualities we *know* the universe has if all we know is $P$", e.g. when you conclude that two universes "have the same qualities" or "are the same". Knowing $P$ doesn't necessarily determine all other facts. That is, we could know only $P$ about each of two universes, and the universes could differ in some unrelated quality.

But since your claim is really entirely about *knowledge of* propositions, it seems to me that you don't need to bring universes into it at all. Instead, just argue that the set of logical consequences of $P$ is equal to the set of logical consequences of $Q$ (because each is a subset of the other, by some basic facts about logical deduction).

If you want to use universes, it's clarifying to think in terms of *sets* of universes. That is, let $V_P$ denote the set of universes in which $P$ is true, and define a *semantic consequence* of $P$ as a proposition that is true in every universe in $V_P$, i.e. a proposition $R$ such that $V_P\subseteq V_R$. (Notice that this is related to Mauro's comment.) Then you can show that if $P$ and $Q$ imply each other, then they have the exact same set of semantic consequences.